# How can I get the pretty error messages when developing on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a rails app and running the server in the development environment on my local host. I'd like to see the error page that I would see when the app is on the production server, and I go to myapp.com/should_show_error_page so that I can style it. Currently, when I go to a page that should display this kind of error, I get the full exception description and stack traces. Starting the server with RAILS_ENV=production isn't enough unless I go to the page from a different machine. I'd appreciate any help.

**Update**

Setting `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` doesn't do it either

**another update**

I'm using [goalie](https://github.com/obvio171/goalie) to generate the error pages, so they're not static.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to access this through the hostname of your computer. For example, I would test it using `http://ryanbigg.local:3000/`. To get the hostname, type `hostname` in your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Just mirror your production server's configuration. Without knowing what that is, I could not comment further.

Comment: Hi I just updated the question for clarity. I want to see the generic "we're sorry, something went wrong" error page when I go to a page that should throw errors from my local host while the app is in the development environment. Currently I'm getting the entire exception description and stack traces. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `public/500.html`. Browse to `http://localhost:3000/500.html` to see what it looks like.